# Changing the Row Wise Columns Group order in rdlc Matix

Tags: reporting-services, report, rdlc

I have an RDLC Matrix Report. In which i have `Columns Group` of `Code,SubCode and Description`. Report Looks like [image: this]

In this picture `Code is Parent Group`, `Sub Code is Child Group of Code`, and `Name/Description is Child Group by SubCode`

However i need below result from these Groups.
[image]

I want to change the row positions of `Code,SubCode and Name/Description`. If i change the order of Grouping, then result not comes correct. Group order should be `Parent Group Code`, `SubCode as Child Group of Code`, and `Name/Description will be Child Group of Sub Code`.

Any help? Is it possible in RDLC Matrix.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to play with `XML` code.

***In your example:***

First, select first `textbox` of your **Name** row and get `Textbox` name by its property. Then go to `XML code` by right click on report, then search by this Textboxname, when you get the `TablixRow` with this textbox name. Copy whole `TablixRow`

Like this,

[image]

Then you just need to Interchange whole `TablixRow` where you require.

So it could be like, copy **Name** `TablixRow` to Top and **Code** `TablixRow` to bottom as per your example.

I know it's bit difficult but this can be the only option to achieve your goal. *Good luck.*

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer but it will `Reverse Grouping` order, Name will be`Parent Group`, `Sub Code will be Child Group of Name` and `Code will Child Group of SubCode` . :( In that case result will be Correct but no `Grouping` will be shown. i.e in my desired `output image` `Code 20` cell is for `21,22,23,24 sub codes one time`. but here it will show me `20 code` for each `21,22,23,24 Sub Code`.

Comment: what you did at last to achieve your goal? @ShahidIqbal